# A melhor forma de usar o PHPMailer

Tags: php, servidor, email, phpmailer

Bom, para disparar emails eu uso o PHPMailer, com o uso do gmail ou hotmail, porém ao usá-lo ele não envia alguns emails, isso se deve ao gmail, que bloqueia ou o hotmail. Neste caso qual forma seria a melhor para usar o PHPMailer, com o email da minha própria hospedagem ou tem alguma outra forma?

Comment: Você pode utilizar as credenciais da sua hospedagem sem problemas Marcelo com tanto que fique atento aos limites de envio (O mesmo se aplica também para o gmail, hotmail, etc). Aqui por exemplo: https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852, você pode ver os limites de envio no gmail.

Seria de grande valia você postar um trecho do seu código para vermos o que pode ser melhorado, se necessário é claro.

Comment: Entendi, eu não vou postar meu código agora porque não estou programando, estou no projeto. Pois dependendo da demanda do cliente a gente usa o que achar mais adequado. @TurqSpl

Comment: @TurqSpl é mais possível o gmail bloquear os envios do que a hospedagem, né !? :/

Comment: Sim exato, dependendo da demanda... Em um projeto por exemplo utilizamos as credenciais do gmail sem problemas. Mas realmente vai mto do projeto